# Do Airbus avionics give good deadstick landing outcomes?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls

We have recently had a second good outcome, in Russia, of a no power landing of an Airbus aircraft. The first was the "miracle on the Hudson".

It appears to me that the avionics of this aircraft are very good at handling the stall v. low speed nose up approach problem.

Does anybody have any insight into this programming?

Comment: You're referring to [this incident](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/23-injured-in-russian-planes-emergency-landing/2019/08/15/a10b1880-bf29-11e9-a8b0-7ed8a0d5dc5d_story.html?noredirect=on), I presume?

Comment: *"Does anybody have any insight into this programming?"* is trivially answered with a "yes" (after all, someone -- likely a number of someones -- wrote that software, hopefully based on a clear specification which itself others would have insight into). Since I presume that isn't the answer you are looking for, what do you *really* want to know?

Comment: The miracle on the Hudson was far from the first dead-stick landing: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_flights_that_required_gliding

Comment: @Eugene Styer, pretty sure he's just asking about Airbus...

Comment: Please make some basic research before posting. Basic research make you refer to incident with their flight number, and searching [such number into wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549) gives you insights. Then you may search for report incident on NTSB or BEA websites. This can help you ask clear questions.

Comment: @MichaelHall, The list includes all types of aircraft, but there were at last two Airbus incidents prior to the Miracle on the Hudson

Comment: @EugeneStyer, it *was* (as far as that list is correct), however, first such incident of A320-family. The A310 incident is not relevant, because A310 was not fly-by-wire and did not feature the control laws and the while A330, involved in the incident of TS-236, does, I am not sure its flight systems degrade the same way (TS-236 did *not* have APU as they had no fuel, but I didn't see any mention whether they lost normal law or not).

Answer (score 4):

Airbus (A320+) normal flight law will, at slow speed¹, maintain angle of attack according to the side-stick position, where full aft deflection gets you to the onset of stall.

However the ram air turbine (at least on A320-family; not sure about A330) does not provide enough power to keep all units on and then the system degrades to direct law, in which the side-sticks just control the deflection of the control surfaces directly. This is similar to any other aircraft except since there is no force feedback the side-stick does not become stiffer with increasing speed.

In the US-1549 flight case (landing on Hudson), they had enough time to start the APU, so all systems were powered and they had normal law and did take advantage of it to let the airplane settle as slow as possible.

In the recent U6-178 flight case we don't yet have enough information whether they did have normal law available.

---

¹ Slower than normal approach speed. At normal speeds, the system maintains wing loading at 1G with neutral side-stick, which can be also described as trimming for current speed. Until the trimmed angle of attack exceeds alpha-limit (12.8° IIRC; 17° is onset of stall, on normal approach should be around half of that), when it switches to maintaining angle of attack.

Comment: Note that US1549 did have a bit of a hiccup in that the software would not allow the recommended pitch attitude at full sidestick deflection. This resulted in some unnecessary damage to the aircraft which caused injury to a flight attendant.